# Show a specific number of Random Items of a list ordered by clicks

Tags: php

I got an area with most viewed items in my view.

What I am actually doing is a query `ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 0, 3` to my database 
and echo this with foreach. At this point it feels a way to static for users. That's why I though about displaying random items of a pool of most viewed items like: `ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 0, 11` and echo with a `for` loop `($i=0; $i>=3;$i++)` and shuffle the items `$items[array_rand($items)];` before echo out.

Actually I don't feel comfortable because it might happen that one item is displayed more then once.

My question is if there is a good other way to solve this in a clean way, without an overhead of code.

Comment: Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply done with proper query. Just insert right table name.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM TABLE_NAME
   ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 0, 11) AS most_clicked
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 3
```

It will return 3 random rows of 11 most clicked in random order.

Comment: this is way smarter! exactly what i was looking for. i appreciate it!